# UITableView, how to change width and height of the whole tableview programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

UITableView, how to change width and height of the whole tableview programmatically?
Or how to change the width of the cell? as for height, I change it with

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

this trick doesn't work for width(((

I've got split-view application by the way. Moreover how to highligh selected cell with another colour? not with blue

Answer (score 5):

To change the width and height of the table view, change the table view's `frame`. Just like you would do with any other view.

Comment: Maybe, but not in Split-View application

Answer (score 3):

Increase the height and width of a table view as such:

```
    tblView.frame = CGRectMake(tblView.frame.origin.x, tblView.frame.origin.y, tblView.frame.size.width + X, tblView.frame.size.height + Y);
```

Here **X, Y** are two `float`.

Comment: Integer? They should be CGFloat!

Comment: @Tobias Haha, They can be Integer. But definitely you like CGFloat more, so go with CGFloat. :)

Comment: It's not about liking it or not, they **are** CGFloat.

Comment: @Zil i will not argue, you seem pretty intense, yes they are CGFloat, I made an edit.